# Deleting a data factory component not working using CI CD pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have implemented CI CD for Azure Data Factory. When I modify a pipeline and publish my changes and deploy it to UAT, the changes reflect properly. The problem arises when I delete any component in dev and publish it and deploy it to the UAT data factory. The changes do not reflect.
How to handle the delete scenario in CI CD pipelines?

As of now I am creating separate releases. Everytime they are deployed, the deleted changes are not reflecting.

Comment: Can you please provide details as to how you have implemented CICD? Is it via Git enabled master branch publish or via ARM template deployment?

Answer (score 1):

CI\CD only merge changes, so it doesn't delete objects.

If you are using the Azure DevOps release pipeline, there is a Microsoft PowerShell sample script that has this ability that you can add to your release pipeline.
Explanation on how to use the script in a release pipeline - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-sample-script)

[Link to the GitHub project containing the actual script](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/main/SamplesV2/ContinuousIntegrationAndDelivery).

Set the parameter deleteDeployment to true (like this: -deleteDeployment $true).